# How to call Solidity Function to return Ether from Smart Contract?

Tags: reactjs, solidity, web3js

I have deployed a smart contract on a local truffle project and I am trying to interact with it in a React project using web3. The following solidity function should send Ether what was previously deposited in the contract to a user address on a boolean condition:

```js
     function Payout() public{

            require( voteEndTime< block.timestamp, "Voting Time is not up. Please come back later" );
            Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];

                if (negativeVotes > positiveVotes){
                    require(!sender.option, "Wrong Vote. Stake is distributed among winners");
                    payable(address(msg.sender)).transfer((stakes*sender.amount) / negativeStakes);
                    }

                else if (positiveVotes > negativeVotes){
                    require(sender.option, "Wrong Vote. Stake is distributed among winners");
                    payable(address(msg.sender)).transfer((stakes*sender.amount) / positiveStakes);
                }

                else{
                    payable(address(msg.sender)).transfer((stakes*sender.amount) / stakes);
                }
            }
```

The contract is definitely able to read the user's address using `msg.sender` because it has worked in the other functions I have. Every other function in the contract is also working fine. I can interact with it and I am able to send Ether to it. The problem occurs when I am trying to return the Ether stored in the contract to an account. I am trying to call my `Payout()` function using the following web3 call in React on button click:

```js
    var response = await BallotContract.methods.Payout().send({ from: account, gas: 310000 })
```

I have specified a higher gas limit, because the contract runs out of gas if I try to use the gas estimation seen below. The function this call is present in looks like this:

```js
     const giveMeMoney = async (e) => {
        const web3 = await new Web3(window.ethereum);
        await window.ethereum.enable();
        
        var Accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts() 
            account = Accounts[0]
            console.log(account)
    
          const gas = await BallotContract.methods.Payout().estimateGas();
          console.log(gas)
          
          var response = await BallotContract.methods.Payout().send({ from: account, gas: 310000 })

    
      }
```

I am able to access the function from the frontend and it is returning the correct string if a "require" condition is not met. My problem is that the contract does not return any Ether if the conditions are met and this line:

```js
    payable(address(msg.sender)).transfer((stakes*sender.amount) / positiveStakes);
```

...is accessed. I am getting the following error:

```
    Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
        at Object.ErrorResponse (errors.js:30)
        at onJsonrpcResult (index.js:162)
        at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (index.js:123)
    ErrorResponse   @   errors.js:30
```

Now I am unsure what could be the problem, because the contract is running perfectly fine if I test it in Remix. Does anybody see the problem or have a workaround for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "out of gas" error is caused by the `transfer` function. This function has a gas limit of 2100; I recommend you use `call`, you can check how [here](https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/).

Also the boolean value of the `Voter` struct defaults to `false`. So if the negative votes win, but the user didn't vote, they still can try to claim the reward, even if the amount is 0. I recommend you check how to use an enum, it can be very useful.